# Navigating facility Through the Hierarchy of Methods is not working in JIdea

Tags: intellij-idea

Normally  there is a facility to Navigating Through the Hierarchy of Methods in JIdea. To do that there are icons displaying on the left side gutter near to the code(like [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-through-the-hierarchy-of-methods.html)). But in my code some of those icons are not visible.

ex : I have interfaces. And i have classes which implement those and implement those methods also. But those interfaces does not indicate that icons to go to the implementations of that methods.What can be the reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Maven, try clean install